# Published reference on the automorphism group of modular curves $X_1(N)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

I wish to cite that the automorphism groups of $X_1(N)$ have already been completely calculated, and what they are, but I am having difficulty finding this calculation in the literature.

I have found in [multiple [22]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2273.pdf) [papers [29]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3267.pdf) on related topics a reference to "F. Momose, Automorphism groups of the modular curves X1(N). Preprint."

I cannot find it. I am wondering if this paper ever made it to publication, or where a copy of it might be? If not, is there a published reference on the topic?

Comment: The only thing I could find was a paper by Kenku and Momose, which discusses the automorphism group of $X_0(N)$, at http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1988__65_1_51_0.pdf. Perhaps the techniques described there could be used to describe the automorphism group of $X_1(N)$.

Comment: Diamond&Shurman's book p.290 finds the Galois group of $\mathbf{C}(X_1(N))/\mathbf{C}(X_1(1))$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)(X_1(N))/\mathbf{Q}(X_1(1))$

Comment: I don't know a reference, the closest I know is the first article you mention. It is close in the sense that $\Gamma_1(N)$ is torsion-free in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ for $N \geq 4$, as in the $\Gamma(N)$ case. Maybe one could try to adapt their proof, possibly replacing $\Gamma(1)$ (the normalizer of $\Gamma(N)$) by the normalizer of $\Gamma_1(N)$ in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, which is known by work of Mong-Lung Lang (MR1813529), see also Zemel (MR3639697)